# PHP/MySQL Database - Dropdown display images

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I am trying to create a simple webpage which will display a certain image when you select a product name in the dropdown menu. The image name will match the ID number in the database: for example a product with the ID "1" will need to echo the "1.png", ID "2" will be "2.png" ect. In the database the ID name is currently set as *ID*. I currently have a working dropdown menu which connects to the MySql database, the code is below.

*func.inc.php*

```
<?php

include_once 'db.inc.php';

function connect(){
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect to the database ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
}
function close(){
    mysql_close();
}
function query(){
    $myData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cadbury_products");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
        echo '<option value="' . $record['ID'] . '">' . $record['NAMEOFPRODUCT'] . '</option>';
        }
}
?>
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
include_once 'func.inc.php';
connect();?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dropdown Menu Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<section>
<article>
<hgroup>
</hgroup>
<p align="center">
    <select name="dropdown">
        <?php query() ?>
    </select>
        <?php close() ?>
</p>
</article>
<article>
</article>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry -  I want to know how to trigger the dropdown so when a certain product is selected from the dropdown it will automatically display a image matching the product ID from the MySQL database. The code I posted is the current PHP dropdown so using this I want to have the image display above the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you can obtain the value of the selectbox, and replace the SRC value of an image with the new link to the image.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<img id="image" src="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $( '#dropdown' ).change(function(){
        $( '#image' ).attr( 'src', $( this ).val() + ".png" );
    })
});
</script>
```

Tested example.